# Why doesn't download work for files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am usign FileUpload in asp.net and it works.

I am using this code to download

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
                string fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" + filePath);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath));
                Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally { }
        }
```

I am uploading `PDF, .xlxs, .jpg, .mp4, .docx` and then downloading them BUT some of them works after downloading and some not i.e. `.xls, .docx` doesn't work and gives error i.e. file is corrupt

Comment: Your not ignoring any exceptions in reality? Are the downloaded files zero length? Have you looked at them in a text editor?

Comment: @AlexK. sir, file is of same size as of uploaded one. extension is same

Comment: What is `ContentType`, specifically what are you setting it to?  Also have you verified the uploaded files as well?

Comment: @juharr Content-type" is simply a header defined in many protocols, such as HTTP, that makes use of MIME types to specify the nature of the file currently being handled.

Comment: @juharr yes sir, they are well and health but gets corrupted after uploading

Comment: @user5820210 I know what content type is.  I was asking how you are setting it.

Comment: @juharr not explicitly, but the way you see

Comment: I see `Response.ContentType = ContentType;`, but what is `ContentType` that is on the right side of the equals sign?  Is it a property or a local variable of some time.  If so how is it set?  Also since that's also the name of a class it probably would be better if you named it something else (assuming you even have control of the code where it comes from).

Comment: it's a property, u can read about it,

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath));
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" + filePath);
Response.End();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
   private byte[] ReadWholeArray(string fileName)
      {
           using (FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
           byte[] output = new byte[sourceFile.Length];
          if (!sourceFile.CanRead) {
            sourceFile.Read(output, 0, sourceFile.Length);
            return output;
            } 
          else
          {
              throw new ApplicationException("No data can be read!");
            }
          }
       }

   public static string GetMimeTypeByFileName(string sFileName)
      {
      string sMime = "application/octet-stream";

   string sExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sFileName);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sExtension)) {
    sExtension = sExtension.Replace(".", "");
    sExtension = sExtension.ToLower();

    if (sExtension == "xls" || sExtension == "xlsx") {
        sMime = "application/ms-excel";
    } else if (sExtension == "doc" || sExtension == "docx") {
        sMime = "application/msword";
    } else if (sExtension == "ppt" || sExtension == "pptx") {
        sMime = "application/ms-powerpoint";
    } else if (sExtension == "rtf") {
        sMime = "application/rtf";
    } else if (sExtension == "zip") {
        sMime = "application/zip";
    } else if (sExtension == "mp3") {
        sMime = "audio/mpeg";
    } else if (sExtension == "bmp") {
        sMime = "image/bmp";
    } else if (sExtension == "gif") {
        sMime = "image/gif";
    } else if (sExtension == "jpg" || sExtension == "jpeg") {
        sMime = "image/jpeg";
    } else if (sExtension == "png") {
        sMime = "image/png";
    } else if (sExtension == "tiff" || sExtension == "tif") {
        sMime = "image/tiff";
    } else if (sExtension == "txt") {
        sMime = "text/plain";
    }
}

return sMime;
}
```

//-----Code

```
       System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
       context.Response.Clear();
       context.Response.ClearHeaders();
       context.Response.ClearContent();
       context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
       context.Response.ContentType = GetMimeTypeByFileName(sFileName);
       context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") + sFileName);
       context.Response.BinaryWrite(ReadWholeArray(FullFilePath));
```

//This will work modern IE